# php regexp last match

Tags: php, regex

Condition:
I have a peace of html code from wysiwig (Brief).
I need to inject readmore link to the last paragrpaph (p-tag)

```
public function injectReadMore($html){
        if( $this->is_html($html) ){
            return preg_replace('#\<\/p\>$#isU',' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-full-dsc">Читать полностью</a>$0', $html);
        } else {
            return '<p>'.$html.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-full-dsc">Читать полностью</a></p>';
        }
    }
```

Yep. What i wrote it's not right. Cuz if

```
$html = '<p>sdfgsdfg</p><div><p>sdfgsdfg</p> </div> ';
```

Fail.

Tried regexp's:

```
'#\<\/p\>[^p]+?$#isU'
'#\<\/p\>[^\/p]+?$#isU'
'#\<\/p\>[^[\/p]]+?$#isU'
```

and the same variants of RegExp. I don't understand something, maybe all;)

Help pls. Thanks, Brothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do with regular string replacement instead of regexp:

```
$pos = strripos($html, '</p>'); // Find last paragraph end
if ($pos !== false) { // Use exact matching, to distinguish 0 from false
    // Insert anchor before it
    $html = substr_replace($html, ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-full-dsc">Читать полностью</a>', $pos, 0);
}
return $html;
```

Comment: what are you `return`ing from?

Comment: @sgroves The function in the question.

Comment: I like this way, but strrpos returns false hard... (php 5.4.11)

Comment: I had the arguments to `strrpos()` backwards (most PHP functions have the needle before the haystack). Fixed it, now it works.

Comment: Changed to `strripos()` to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex pattern with negative lookahead (?!…)

```
</p>(?!.*</p>)
```

[image: regexp]

Example: http://www.debuggex.com/r/rgV-ddCbL-BH_rL_/0

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead but remember to escape your html.

```
preg_replace('/\<\/p\>(?!.*\<\/p\>)/isU', '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-full-dsc">Читать полностью</a></p>', $html);
```